# Country triples with two common points

Tags: geography, knowledge

In this puzzle, we only consider *independent* countries and we do *not*
count overseas territories as actual part of a country. We say that three countries form a **well-connected triple**, if each two of
them share a piece of common border with strictly positive length.
Most of these well-connected triples furthermore meet at a point (at
least theoretically).

**Q**: What are the eight well-connected triples that share (at least) two  points common to all three countries?

Comment: so basically you're looking for a country that lies between 2 other countries and has no other neighbours?

Comment: @Novarg: No, not exactly. Azerbaijan consists of two disconnected parts, and between the two parts Armenia is bordering Iran.

Comment: The "correct answer" sign goes to Gamow who found the last (and hence hardest) answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Quick and easy answers:**

> 1. Mongolia, China, and Russia
> 2. Switzerland, Austria, and Liechtenstein
> 3. India, China, and Nepal
> 4. India, China, and Bhutan

**Three further answers found by shyos:**

> 5. Ukraine, Romania, and Moldova
> 6. South Africa, Mozambique, and Swaziland
> 7. France, Spain, and Andorra

**And finally the "weirdest" solution:**

> 8. Armenia, Azerbaijan, and Iran

Answer (score 5):

Based on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landlocked_country#Landlocked_by_two_countries) there are 7 country that are landlocked by two other countries.

> Seven landlocked countries are surrounded by only two mutually
>   bordering neighbors:
>
> - Andorra (between France and Spain)
> - Bhutan (between India and China)
> - Liechtenstein (one of the "doubly landlocked" countries, between       Switzerland and Austria)
> - Moldova (between Ukraine and Romania)
> - Mongolia (between Russia and China)
> - Nepal (between India and China)
> - Swaziland (between South Africa and Mozambique)
>
> To this group could be added two de facto states with no or limited
>   international recognition:
>
> - South Ossetia (between Russia and Georgia)
> - Transnistria (between Ukraine and Moldova)